# CENTRAR LOGO DE MI WEB HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap

Hice mi web en HTML y el logo me queda desentrado.

Aqui les dejo la imagen para que vean a que me refiero. Necesito que este centrado dentro del circulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui les dejo el codigo

```
<!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h1>PERALTA RAMOS</h1>
                            <h2>INMOBILIARIA | CONSULTORIA EN ADMINISTRACIÓN</h2>
                            <p>PAGINA BAJO CONSTRUCCION</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#intro">INTRO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">HISTORIA</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#work">SERVICIOS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACTO</a></li>
                            <!--<li><a href="#elements">Elements</a></li>-->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
```

Comment: ¿y el css? Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Usa el **[code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78).**

Comment: `#header .logo {
   width: 5.5rem;
   height: 5.5rem;
   line-height: 5.5rem;
   border: solid 1px #ffffff;
   border-radius: 100%;
  }

   #header .logo .icon:before {
    font-size: 2rem;
   }`

Comment: '#header .logo {
    width: 4.75rem;
    height: 4.75rem;
    line-height: 4.75rem;
   }

    #header .logo .icon:before {
     font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
'

Comment: Agrega el CSS a la pregunta ya que los comentarios son usos provisionales.

Comment: @Rubén no he subido mi css por el hecho de que tiene 1500 lineas

Comment: En ese caso deberías crear un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto.

```
elemento {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% -(50px/2));
    left: calc(50% -(50px/2));
}
```

En este caso seria

```
.logo img {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% -(50px/2));
        left: calc(50% -(50px/2));
}
```

Comment: vos decis que borre esas cuatro lineas y la cabie por 

`.logo img {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% -(50px/2));
        left: calc(50% -(50px/2));
}`

Comment: @SalvaCastro no, solo agregalo a tu css..

Comment: Ahi se soluciono el problema desde la compu. Pero cuando entro con el celular se mueve de nuevo y no queda centrado. Sera por algo?

Comment: Ahi se soluciono el problema desde la compu. Pero cuando entro con el celular se mueve de nuevo y no queda centrado. Sera por algo?

Comment: No veo la necesidad de usar posición absoluta, bastaría con definir alto y ancho del contenedor en 50px (medidas de la imagen) y aplicar un margen interno (padding), aproximadamente de 35px.